# Multiple calculations of the same value in CASE - is it performed multiple times for each record, or once?

Tags: postgresql, optimization

I apologize if this has been asked before, but I googled and could not come up with a good search to find out.
I have next statement:

```
CASE
    WHEN p."PlanPeriod_End" >= (CASE WHEN p."FactPeriod_End" IS NULL THEN NOW() ELSE p."FactPeriod_End" END)
    --                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    THEN 'нет'
    ELSE (CASE WHEN p."FactPeriod_End" IS NULL THEN NOW() ELSE p."FactPeriod_End" END** - p."PlanPeriod_End")::TEXT
    --   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
END
```

As you can see, I have...

```
CASE WHEN p."FactPeriod_End" IS NULL THEN NOW() ELSE p."FactPeriod_End" END
```

... twice in my statement. My question is, in this case will it calculated internally one time for every CASE instance, or will it be calculated twice for each record?
In other word, is there some inner optimization for such cases implemented in pgSQL, or I should optimize it some other way?
Sorry for my bad English, thank you in advance.

I know I can try to simulate some data and try to run some tests, but I believe an input from professionals who know what exactly going on out there may bring much more accurate results in this research.